# CSVhelper writefield method adds empty line between data chunks. How to avoid the empty lines between data chunks?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to write a CSV file with values that I am constantly fetching from the `BlockingCollection` obj. Instrument outputs comma-separated string values constantly, which I am writing to the Queue using the Producer-Consumer design pattern. I am enumerating the Queue at the consumer end, then converting the string into a list.

Finally iterating over the list and writing the result to the CSV file row by row. I don't have blank lines when iterating the list. I am getting one empty line between every consumer enumeration. How to avoid this empty line?

The part of the code which is performing the above operation is below:

```cs
public void Consumer_current()
{
    Stopwatch Consumer_time = new Stopwatch();
    double time = 0.0;
    var sw = new StreamWriter("sample.csv", false);
    var csv_write = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Consumer_time.Start();
    

    // Consumer Task constantly checking the Queue and enumerating    
    foreach (var current_string in current_data.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        var item_List = current_string.Split(',').ToList();

        // Iterating the list, writing the values to CSV file
        foreach (var item in item_List)       
        {
            
             
            time += 1;

            var record = time + "," + item;

            csv_write.WriteField(record, false);
            Console.WriteLine(record);

            csv_write.NextRecord();
        }
    }

   
    csv_write.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine("flushing");
}
```

Edit 1:

`csv_write.NextRecord();`  2nd call is removed now.It is not making the difference and it was left accidentally while changing the code.

Added Producer code below:

```
 public void Produce_current () {

     Stopwatch DataCapture_time = new Stopwatch ();

     DataCapture_time.Start ();

     while (DataCapture_time.Elapsed <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds (20)) {
         while (DataCapture_time.Elapsed <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds (1.3)) {

         }

         device_instance.WriteString ("FETC:ELOG? 10000,(@1)");
         var Data_log_results = device_instance.ReadString ();

         current_data.Add (Data_log_results);
     }
     current_data.CompleteAdding ();
 }
```

Comment: It looks like there may be an unintended call to `csv_write.NextRecord()`. You might double check that both calls are required to output the intended results.

Comment: Can we see the data coming from `current_data.GetConsumingEnumerable()`? Everything looks fine, although there are some things that could be done more proper, it should work just fine without blank lines. I am going to say there is empty strings coming from that method.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't dispose your streams. With C# 8, you can just put `using` in front of `var` (using keyword instead of using block).

Comment: Also I tried     var item_List = current_string.Split(',').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList(); Still empty line is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks "Andy" for the hint, and others for their time.

After doing analysis I have figured it out that the instrument (Keysight - N6705B, Power analyzer) was writing the internal memory buffer with string chunk and "\n". Every-time when I read a new value from the internal memory of the device it appends a new line character and that was reflecting when writing to the csv file.
Note: The data from the device is in ASCII format.

To fix this issue I slightly modified my code in the Producer_current() block.

```cs
{
  device_instance.WriteString("FETC:ELOG? 10000,(@1)");
  var Data_log_results = device_instance.ReadString();

  //modified part of code to remove the new line character and carriage return - I am using the windows OS

  Data_log_results = Data_log_results.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');

}
```

The above code works perfect for someone who wants to write CSV file row by row from dynamically changing list using CsvHelper.

Anyone stuck reading from the instrument buffer need to remove "\n" as mentioned above.